# How to speed up this TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a TSQL select query that is running "slow"

```
SELECT 
    CustomerKey
    ,ProductKey
    ,RepresentativeKey
    ,ReportingDateKey   
    ,SUM(i.InvoiceQuantity) AS InvoiceQuantity
    ,SUM(i.InvoiceQuantityKg) AS InvoiceQuantityKg
    ,SUM(i.BrutoInvoiceLineAmount) AS BrutoInvoiceLineAmount
    ,SUM(i.EndOfYearDiscount) AS EndOfYearDiscount
    ,SUM(i.NettoInvoiceLineAmount) AS NettoInvoiceLineAmount
    ,SUM(i.TotalLineCostPrice) AS CostPrice
    ,SUM(i.MarginAmount) AS MarginAmount

FROM FactInvoices i

WHERE 
    i.DossierKey =2
    AND i.ReportingDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY
    CustomerKey
    ,ProductKey
    ,RepresentativeKey
    ,ReportingDateKey
```

I'm running the query in SSMS 32bit.
Execution time is 17-21s, I have tested adding non clustered indexs on DossierKey and ReportingDate, but this is only slowing down the query.

The table has about 6.04M record and this result set is giving back 1M records.
It's running on SQL 2016 Developers edition.
Server specs: 8core 16gb ram and HDD => Virual server.

Looking at the execution plan, I can't find any improvements.
How do I speed up? More hardware? But I don't think that will help because the server is not fully used when running this query.

Edit:
Execution Plan:
[image]

Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dx1]
ON [dbo].[FactInvoices] ([DossierKey],[ReportingDate])
INCLUDE ([CustomerKey],[ProductKey],[ReportingDateKey],[RepresentativeKey],[InvoiceQuantity],[InvoiceQuantityKg],[BrutoInvoiceLineAmount],[NettoInvoiceLineAmount],[MarginAmount],[EndOfYearDiscount],[TotalLineCostPrice])
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to analyze the SQL Plan for starters, and investigate if there are covering indexes you could use, or even a filtered index. A simple index is probably not going to help much.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Do you mean the query is returning 1M aggregated rows? 17-21 seconds seems reasonable, considering client and network time.

Comment: @SqlZim adding the index, is slowing down the query to 23-26s

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm running the query directly on the server with SSMS

Comment: @Phoenix what is the query time you're expecting to get here? Right now the execution plan is straight forward and you have a pretty simple query.

Comment: How are you timing the query? Does it start bringing results back immediately?

Comment: put it in a view? that might cache it a bit...

Comment: @Phoenix, SSMS is a client like any other. What time do you get if you select the discard query results option?

Comment: Try filtering your index on DossierKey = 2. In all honesty 17 seconds to return 1 million rows seems OK.

Comment: @Zane as fast as possible, but it has to be below 10s

Comment: @Phoenix can you post the table structure and your current indexing?

Comment: @DanGuzman With discard of results I get the result back in 4s

Comment: if you want it very fast i'd sum each day into a separate table and continue populating this table by running a script each night to sum yesterday. You can then query this table so you don't need group bys

Comment: @Zane only an Clustered index on a incremental Id field, updating post with table schema

Comment: Please add clustered index on IDfield,DossierKey and ReportingDate to start of. Run this query multiple times to make sure SQL server caches the execution plan

Comment: So if it takes 17 seconds with results and 4 seconds with discarding results then 13 seconds is taken up by SSMS dealing with the result set. How long does your application take?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes! This is what I think a few of us were driving at. It doesn't really seem like the query is running slow. It could be SSMS taking time to render the result set or even the lag time between the box and his local machine.

Comment: the viewing application is SSRS and is realy slow, and is getting time out connection error

Comment: Wait—you're getting a *connection* timeout error? Are you sure that's even anything to do with the query? (Also, is your SSRS server connected to your SQL Server with a fast network connection? Because bringing back a million rows of this stuff is going to be quite a lot of traffic, I'd have thought...)

Comment: @Phoenix wait you're trying to display 1 Million rows in a single SSRS report? Displaying that many rows in a single report can definitely cause SSRS to slow down massively. Also why would a report bring in such a large volume of data? How much information can your user reasonably parse through?

Comment: @MattGibson SSRS and SQL server are running on the same server. Connection is working because change the query with out the grouping (and only the aggregations is working) time out connection is because that Query is slower then 60s

Comment: @Zane this is the base query, I joining this to my DIM data and then re grouping it. But I need a range of 2y(the 1M rec) to join with the DIM tables and but if i can increase performance on this part overall performance will increase as well

Comment: @Phoenix but you said yourself that the query runs in 17s to ssms and 4 seconds when discarding the results. I don't think your problem is that the query runs slow. I think it's that you're sending too much data to SSRS. Especially now that we know it takes over 60 seconds to run a query that takes 17 in SSMS.

Comment: @Zane Investigating the new information as we speek, Indeed the "performance" lost can be located some where else

Answer (score 4):

For this query:

```
SELECT CustomerKey, ProductKey, RepresentativeKey, ReportingDateKey,
       . . .
FROM FactInvoices i
WHERE i.DossierKey = 2 AND
      i.ReportingDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY CustomerKey, ProductKey, RepresentativeKey, ReportingDateKey;
```

I would recommend an index on `FactInvoices(DossierKey, ReportingDate, CustomerKey, ProductKey, RepresentativeKey)`.  The first two are the primary elements of the index used for the `WHERE` clause.  The remaining three columns may be useful for the aggregation.  You could also include all the additional columns used in the query.

Answer (score 2):

*This is an article I wrote on speeding up a query.*

If your query is slow, you can check the execution plan for possible areas of speed up.

Well, I have done that and find that it does not always help.  The same execution plan can take seconds to run or go off into never never land and be killed after 7 minutes.

I solved this recently using a variety of techniques that I haven't seen mentioned in one place before and wanted to help anyone else in the same situation.  The solution usually returned within 2 seconds.

Here is what I did.

**Starting Query**

This is a fairly basic query.  It reports sales orders and allows the user to specify up to 6 optional where criteria.

•   If the user does not enter a criteria for a value, for example Country, its criteria string is set to '' and Country is not checked.

•   If the user does enter a criteria for a value,  its criteria string is bracketed by '%..%'.  For example, if the user enters 'Tin', strCountry is set to '%Tin%' and all countries with 'Tin' in its name are selected.  (Argentina and Martinique for example.)

```
SELECT Top 1000
    SalesHeader.InvoiceNumber
    ,SalesHeader.CompanyName
    ,SalesHeader.Street
    ,SalesHeader.City
    ,SalesHeader.Region
    ,SalesHeader.Country
    ,SalesHeader.SalesDate
    ,SalesHeader.InvoiceTotal
    ,SalesLineItem.LineItemNbr
    ,SalesLineItem.PartNumber
    ,SalesLineItem.Quantity
    ,SalesLineItem.UnitPrice
    ,SalesLineItem.Quantity * SalesLineItem.UnitPrice    as ExtPrice
    ,PartMaster.UnitWeight
    ,SalesLineItem.Quantity * PartMaster.UnitWeight      as ExtWeight
FROM dbo.SalesHeader 
left join dbo.SalesLineItem    on SalesHeader.InvoiceNumber    = SalesLineItem.InvoiceNumber
left join dbo.PartMaster       on SalesLineItem.PartNumber        = PartMaster.PartNumber
where
    (@strCountry = ''        or Country like @strCountry)
    and
    (@strCompanyName = ''    or CompanyName like @strCompanyName)
    and
    (@strPartNumber = ''     or SalesLineItem.PartNumber like @strPartNumber)
    and
    (@strInvoiceNumber = ''  or SalesHeader.InvoiceNumber like @strInvoiceNumber)
    and
    (@strRegion = ''         or Region like @strRegion)
    and
    (@mnyExtPrice = 0        or (SalesLineItem.Quantity * SalesLineItem.UnitPrice) > @mnyExtPrice)
Order By
    InvoiceNumber,
    Region,
    ExtPrice
```

I am taking this from a data warehouse I worked on.  There were 260,000 records in the full query.  We limited the return to 1,000 records as a user would never want more than that.

Sometimes the query would take 10 seconds or less and sometimes we would have to kill it after over 7 minutes had gone by.  A user is not going to wait 7 minutes.

**What We Came Up With**

There are different techniques to speed up a query.  The following is our resulting query.  I go over each of the techniques used below.

This new query generally returned results in 2 seconds or less.

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber
    ,Company
    ,Street
    ,City
    ,Region
    ,Country
    ,SalesDate
    ,InvoiceTotal
    ,LineItemNbr
    ,PartNumber
    ,Quantity
    ,UnitPrice
    ,ExtPrice
    ,UnitWeight
    ,ExtWeight
FROM 
(
    SELECT top 1000
        IdentityID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SalesDate], [Country], [Company], [PartNumber]) as RowNbr
    FROM dbo.SalesCombined with(index(NCI_SalesDt))
    where
        (@strCountry = ''        or Country like @strCountry)
        and
        (@strCompany = ''        or Company like @strCompany)
        and
        (@strPartNumber = ''     or PartNumber like @strPartNumber)
        and
        (@strInvoiceNumber = ''  or InvoiceNumber like @strInvoiceNumber)
        and
        (@strRegion = ''         or Region like @strRegion)
        and
        (@mnyExtPrice = 0        or ExtPrice > @mnyExtPrice)
) SubSelect
Inner Join dbo.SalesCombined on SubSelect.IdentityID = SalesCombined.IdentityID
Order By
    RowNbr
```

**Technique 1 - Denormalize the data.**

I was fortunate in two ways:

•   The data was small enough to create a second copy of it.

•   The data did not change very often.  This meant I could structure the second copy optimized for querying and allow updating to take a while.

The SalesHeader, SalesLineItem and PartMaster tables were merged into the single SalesCombined table.

The calculated values were stored in the SalesCombined table as well.

Note that I left the original tables in place.  All code to update those tables was still valid.  I had to create additional code to then propagate the changes to the SalesCombined table.

**Technique 2 - Created An Integer Identity Value**

The first field of this denormalized table is an integer identity value.  This was called IdentityID.

Even if we had not denormalized the data, an integer identity value in SalesHeader could have been used for the join between it and SalesLineItem and speeded the original query up a bit.

**Technique 3 - Created A Clustered Index On This Integer Identity Value**

I created a clustered index on this IdentityID value.  This is the fastest way to find a record.

**Technique 4 - Created A Unique, Non-Clustered Index On The Sort Fields**

The query's output is sorted on four fields, SalesDate, Country, Company, PartNumber.  So I created an index on these fields SalesDate, Country, Company and PartNumber.

Then I added the IdentityID to this index.  This index was noted as Unique.  This allowed SQL Server to go from the sort fields to the address, essentially, of the actual record as quickly as possible.

**Technique 5: Include In the Non-Clustered Index All 'Where Clause' Fields**

A SQL Server index can include fields that are not part of the sort.  (Who thought of this?  It's a great idea.)  If you include all where clause fields in the index, SQL Server does not have to look up the actual record to obtain this data.

This is the normal look up process:
1)  Read the index from disk.
2)  Go to the first entry on the index.
3)  Find the address of the first record from that entry.
4)  Read that record from disk.
5)  Find any fields that are part of the where clause and apply the criteria.
6)  Decide if that record is included in the query.

If you include the where clause fields in the index:
1)  Read the index from disk.
2)  Go to the first entry on the index.
3)  Find any fields that are part of the where clause (stored in the index) and apply the criteria.
4)  Decide if that record is included in the query.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_InvcNbr] ON [dbo].[SalesCombined]
(
    [SalesDate] ASC,
    [Country] ASC,
    [CompanyName] ASC,
    [PartNumber] ASC,
    [IdentityID] ASC
)
INCLUDE [InvoiceNumber],
    [City],
    [Region],
    [ExtPrice]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
                ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

The execution plan for the original query.

[Click Here To See Original Query Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkCq5.png)

The execution plan for our final query is much simpler - to start, it just reads the index.

[Click Here To See Final Query Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqrNZ.png)

**Technique 6: Created A Sub-Query To Find The IdentityID Of Each Record To Output And Their Sort Order**

I created a sub-query to find the records to output and the order in which to output them.  Note the following:

•   **Technique 7** - It explicitly says to use the NCI_InvcNbr index that has all of the fields needed in it.

•   **Technique 8**- It uses the Row_Number function to generate an integer for each row that will be output.  These values are generated 1, 2 and 3 in the order given by the fields in the ORDER BY section of that line.

**Technique 9: Create An Enclosing Query With All Of The Values**

This query specifies the values to print.  It uses the Row_Number values to know the order in which to print.  Note that the inner join is done on the IdentityID field which uses the Clustered index to find each record to print.

**Techniques That Did Not Help**

There were two techniques that we tried that did not speed up the query.  These statements are both added to the end of a query.

•   OPTION (MAXDOP 1) limits the number of processors to one.  This will prevent any parallelism from being done.  We tried this when we were experimenting with the query and had parallelism in the execution plan.

•   OPTION (RECOMPILE) causes the execution plan to be recreated every time the query is run.  This can be useful when different user selections can vary the query results.

Hope this can be of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you already indexed this query and it still with a bad performance, you can try partition your table by DossierKey.

and change

```
WHERE i.DossierKey = 2
```

to

```
WHERE $PARTITION.partition_function_name( 2)
```

https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/12/table-partitioning-in-sql-server/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql

Comment: Table partitioning isn't really a tool for performance. I definitely wouldn't build a partition to help 1 particular query. It's much more likely that a specific query would be benefited by a covering index.